# Use useState in useImperativeHandle, the first call will not update the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do I call the `show` function to update the status for the first time? The parent component calls the child component method and successfully calls the `show` method, but the `useState` is not updated initially.

```js
const [showPop, toggleShowPop] = useState(false);

useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
  hide: () => {
    toggleShowPop(false)
  },
  show: () => {
    toggleShowPop(true)
  },
  showPop
}), [showPop]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('showPop',showPop) // first time showPop is not update
}, [showPop]);
```

Comment: What exactly is logged? You should see `showPop: false` when the component is initialized, before any method gets called from the parent. Is that just what you're observing, or something more? And what does `toggleShowPop` actually do?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [working example](https://playcode.io/1533397) that accomplishes what you are asking. This is the complete code:

```js
// index.jsx
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import MyComponent from './App.jsx';

function App() {
  const myComponentRef = useRef();

  const handleShow = () => {
    myComponentRef.current.show();
  }

  const handleHide = () => {
    myComponentRef.current.hide();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent ref={myComponentRef} />
      <button onClick={handleShow}>Show</button>
      <button onClick={handleHide}>Hide</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot( 
  document.querySelector('#root')
).render(<App />);
```

```js
// App.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from 'react';

const MyComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [showPop, toggleShowPop] = useState(false);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    hide: () => {
      toggleShowPop(false)
    },
    show: () => {
      toggleShowPop(true)
    },
  }), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('showPop updated', showPop);
  }, [showPop]);

  console.log('showPop initial', showPop); // log initial state

  return (
    <div>
      {showPop && <div>Show pop is true</div>}
    </div>
  );
});

export default MyComponent;
```

The key thing is that you need to use `useRef().current` to access the internal `show` and `hide` methods of the component to manipulate the state.

Comment: I found the problem, the parent component called the child component immediately after using useState, the child component did not update the state at this time,(thanks! @Aaron Meese)